# Spring Data JPA CRUD Repository Interface JPQL @Query generating custom query fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am working on a rest-based (not restful) api and have the following problem. Trying to create a custom query with JPQL to update customer information. Member email in entity customer is unique, so I have to write my own query otherwise it causes unique constraintviolationsexception. I found this out so far and now I am trying to fix by writing a Custom query in Spring CRUD Repository Interface with JPQL.

**CustomerController**

```
@RestController public class CustomerController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;
    
    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public List<CustomerDTO> allCustomer(){
        return customerService.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/customers/{id}")
    public CustomerDTO oneCustomer(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        return customerService.findOneById(id);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/customers")
    public CustomerDTO addCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        return customerService.saveCustomer(customerDTO);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/customers/{id}")
    public CustomerDTO updateCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        return customerService.updateCustomer(customerDTO);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/customers/{id}")
    public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
         customerService.deleteCustomer(id);
    }

}
```

**CustomerService**

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDTO customerDTO;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerService.class);

    // Gebe Liste von Kunden zurück
    public List<CustomerDTO> findAll() {
        var it = customerRepository.findAll();
        var customerList = new ArrayList<CustomerDTO>();
        for (Customer customer : it) {
            customerDTO = convertToDto(customer);
            customerList.add(customerDTO);
        }
        return customerList;
    }

    // Gebe einen bestimmten Kunden zurück
    public CustomerDTO findOneById(long id) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(id);
        CustomerDTO customerDTO = convertToDto(customer);
        return customerDTO;
    }

    // Speicher einen Kunden in der Datenbank und gebe diesen zurück
    public CustomerDTO saveCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        if (customerDTO != null) {
            Customer savedObject = customerRepository.save(convertToEntity(customerDTO));
            // Abrufen der gespeicherten Entity und Umwandlung in DTO, weil DTO nun weitere Werte enthält als zuvor (Id & timestamp)
            CustomerDTO responseCustomer = convertToDto(customerRepository.findById(savedObject.getId()).get());
            return responseCustomer;
        } else {
            log.info("Kunden speichern in die Datenbank fehlgeschlagen");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Kundendaten bearbeiten
    public CustomerDTO updateCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        if (customerDTO != null) {
            Customer updatedObject = customerRepository.updateCustomerByDTO(convertToEntity(customerDTO));
            // Abrufen der gespeicherten Entity und Umwandlung in DTO
            Customer getCustomer = customerRepository.findById(updatedObject.getId()).get();
            CustomerDTO responseCustomer = convertToDto(getCustomer);
            return responseCustomer;
        } else {
            log.info("Bearbeiten des Kunden in der Datenbank fehlgeschlagen!");
            return null;
        }

    }

    // Lösche Kunden aus der Datenbank
    public void deleteCustomer(Long id) {
        customerRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    // Umwandlung von Entity zu DTO Objekt
    public CustomerDTO convertToDto(Customer customer) {
        CustomerDTO customerDTO = modelMapper.map(customer, CustomerDTO.class);
        return customerDTO;
    }

    // Umwandlung von DTO zu Entity Objekt
    private Customer convertToEntity(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        Customer customer = modelMapper.map(customerDTO, Customer.class);
        return customer;
    }

}
```

**CustomerRepository**

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    /*
     * Here we can create our custom search queries on CustomerRepository
     */

    List<Customer> findBySurname(String surname);

    Customer findById(long id);

    Customer findByEmail(String email);
    
    //Update Customer workaround email field ConstraintViolationException
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Customer c SET c.given_name = :#{#customer.given_name}, c.surname = :#{#customer.surname}, c.birthday= :#{#customer.birthday},"
            + " c.street_address = :#{#customer.street_address}, c.city = :#{#customer.city}, c.postal_code = :#{#customer.postal_code},"
            + " c.phone_number = :#{#customer.phone_number}, c.balance= :#{#customer.balance}, c.bonuspoints= :#{#customer.bonuspoints}"
            + " WHERE c.id = :#{#customer.id} ")
    Customer updateCustomerByDTO(@Param("customer") Customer customer);
    
}
```

This causes following Stacktrace and I dont found any solution so far.
**Stacktrace**

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository' defined in com.yildiz.tradilianz.customer.CustomerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.yildiz.tradilianz.customer.Customer com.yildiz.tradilianz.customer.CustomerRepository.updateCustomerByDTO(com.yildiz.tradilianz.customer.Customer)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at .......`

Stacktrace is telling me, that validation is false but I Think my JPQL Query is correct. I am confused do you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get the syntax you are using in the update?

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/update-queries.html from here. I thought it is valid JPQL?

Comment: Since you are passing in a `Customer` entity to the update method, why not just update the entire entity?  Is your intention to really update only certain fields?

Comment: I pass whole entity to avoid editing manually fields. I thought it would be better if I keep this dynamically. Yes because email field should not be updateable in my case. Maybe it is not logic but it is a scenario I should learn to handle..

Comment: _Don't_ do it this way unless you really want to update only certain fields.

Comment: Hi Tim, could you explain why it is not a good idea to make a custom JPQL query to modify an entity (certain fields of entity). Thank you anyway for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Naming

There might be a problem with naming. You didn't include your Customer entity. Does it really use a snake_case naming convention as your JPQL query suggests?

In JPQL you should use **the exact field names as in a Java class**. Usually, it's camelCase naming convention, while snake_case is used in a database.

#### Return value

Definitely there is a problem with a method signature. Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as a return type.

Assuming you really did use a snake_case for Customer and after changing the return type of `updateCustomerByDTO` to void, the query works fine.

```java
void updateCustomerByDTO(@Param("customer") Customer customer);
```

Another hint of how you may approach the non-updatable email problem. You can just use a `@Column` annotation with the `updatable` attribute set to `false`. If you really never want to update an email, it will be much easier.

```java
@Entity
class Customer {
   ...
   @Column(updatable = false)
   String email;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. Yes after I corrected naming because in my Entity and POJO I use camelcase (thought JPQL require snake case because of the example i seen) the query works but there take no changes on database effect. So if I make a PUT Request with different values it keeps to be the same. I debugged to see if customerDTO has right values and it is correct. Something is going wrong in another place. May I ask you if I use the @Column(updateable = false) annotation, do I have to write anyway a custom JPQL query or does Spring handle the  constraintviolationsexception for me?

Comment: I just had to take additioanally the id from Request and update my Customerservice and the CustomerRepository. Your post solved my problem. If it is bad practice to do it that way, I would be happy to hear again from you why we should use @Colum(updateable = false) instead.. Kind Regards

Comment: Glad it worked! @Column(updatable=false) is just designed for such cases. With this annotation, you don't need a custom query anymore, so less code and easier to maintain.